# Почему не могу выкинуть исключение?

Tags: php

Есть такой, проверяю его на числа в случае неудачи кидаю исключение

```
           $number = intval($_GET['id']);

            if($number)
                $result = $number;
            else
                new CHttpException(404, 'Not found');
```

В итоге если пробую передать строку то проходит и не могу выкинуть исключение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка найдена элементарно просто. Исключение нужно было не только создать, но и бросить.

```
$number = intval($_GET['id']);

if($number)
    $result = $number;
else
    throw new CHttpException(404, 'Not found');
```

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим Вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: да это вроде бы ответ. Там не хватало `throw` для исключения.

Comment: @NickVolynkin вроде сам автор вопроса и отвечает себе, не надо такое в вопрос вставлять?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: в данном редком случае это именно ответ. В вопрос вставлять — если дополнительная информация по проблеме. Тут же проблема очевидна из имеющегося кода, если внимательно смотреть. Ошибка простая, но, наверное, распространенная. Многие хоть раз да забывают написать `throw`.